How can I repair this badly peeling ceiling finish?
The material on the ceiling is falling off. What are my patch options?
See photos: https://imgur.com/a/tw36DCE
I know the most effective solution might be to scrape any loose parts (which might be the entire ceiling, once I start scraping), but people currently live in this bedroom, so that doesn't seem like a good option right now. It appears to be stucco (popcorn ceiling). The material is very thick and stiff, unlike what I've seen peeling paint do.
Also, I am getting an inspection done soon where I want the needed repairs to be relatively visible, so a full scrape and paint wouldn't be good for that.
Is there a way to temporarily patch the areas, to prevent the material from continuing to peel away due to gravity?
I don't think duct tape along the edges would work. (Duct tape along the edges, then cover the exposed areas with plastic and tape that up)
I already addressed the water/moisture issue. This is the top floor of the house. The roof has these foot-wide air vent pipes, and the caps came off, so rain kept falling directly above this ceiling.


do not use duact tape, it is to strong, use the masking tape (blue)

That looks like water (or at least moisture) damage to me.  I'd want to replace the ceiling, if only to see what caused that.  But also replacing the ceiling will give you a guaranteed good substrate for paint.

I used some drywall joint compound, rubbed it on the ceiling above the peeling pieces, pushed the pieces back in place, and then added more compound on the edges of the pieces. Then I'll cover the exposed areas with compound, and then add texture like the other Answer advised.
It's been good for 48 hours so far, and the peeling has not started again. I'll see what happens. It's a fun little experiment.
After photo: https://imgur.com/a/ZacfXjz
Now I just saw a video of someone patching a much smaller crack with a specific mixture, so I guess it's the same principle (just on a much smaller scale)
https://youtu.be/tgUeI4LHbas?si=BCuWIrOieKhMeLfp
Now I just found someone using a spray adhesive instead. https://youtu.be/gnaAtqciy6c?si=h-vFaoH1Yjzok_Bj

Followup questions are not appropriate in answers. Please take the [tour].

The ceiling is textured, but it is not "popcorn".  Have it tested to see if there is lead. The results will then determine the procedure.
What has fallen off is the result of moisture getting in the drywall.  You must correct that problem first.
When the area is dry, the remaining loose edges must be scraped off. Then skimmed with drywall compound (general purpose will work ). When dry, lightly sand to taper edges or I wipe the edges and any ridges with a damp sponge (grout sponge), so there is no dust.
The texture then can be sprayed on. Matching takes some practice. Get a big piece of cardboard or old plywood.  Do Not tape off close to the repair area.  This will make a straight line along the tape and make the repair more noticable.  I usually tape plastic as protection at least 3 feet from the edge of the area to be repaired.  When possible I leave the entire wall uncovered and ease off on the texture as I move out. When dry you can paint.
I'm sure there are all kinds of short cuts to this that will look horrible and make a final good repair more difficult.  I cannot recommend any of those.
Even done by one person, this is something that can be done during non sleeping hours and completed in stages over 3 days allowing for drying time.

Let's assume that it's lead. It's a really old house.  Does that change the procedure (other than goggles, masks and covers)?

And please see my "Answer." I would love to hear your opinion.

Also, whatever this peeling stuff is, it's really thick. In order to level the ceiling, would I be able to spray to that much thickness? I figure I'd have to level it with compound first, then paint on the texture. Yes/no?
